# Is an MX record needed?

Tags: domain-name-system, email, mx-record

We have a testing server with its own domain name.  We don't want any email to be sent from this domain.  We don't want any email to be received on this domain.

Is it ok to remove the MX record from the DNS?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, an MX record is there only for incoming mail.

Comment: While this is true, MX records are also used by some spam detecting mechanisms. So if you try to send outgoing mail to some other server, it might reject you because of missing or incorrect DNS entries, including your MX record (is there an MX record for the domain you are trying to send from, if so, does it point to the server you are sending from ...)

Comment: Isaac - The OP stated that he doesn't want to send OR receive email from or to this server. In addition, any spam mechanism that uses the MX record for a domain (instead of the SPF record for the domain) is doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

mx is only needed if there is no a or aaaa records, and it must be a hostname mx

not define mx is not to decleare there is no email on that domain

sadly some antispam solotions thinks that missing mx is same as no mail on that domain name, fail

so to be clear, mx is not needed, as it was questioned here